# Is there a way to query Databricks DBFS or parquets via .NET for Apache Spark?

Tags: c#, .net, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

In a nutshell, I'm trying to explore the possibility of serving data from a Databricks workspace to a C#/.NET application for user interaction and ad-hoc queries. I've spent some time setting up [Databricks-Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect), which seems to be working insofar that I can run Python Spark jobs on the Databricks cluster from my local machine.

I'm also trying to walk through setup and execute samples from [.NET for Apache Spark](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/data/spark)

My problem is that I'm having trouble finding documentation, samples, or demos of anything involving these two working together. Is it possible to set up a spark session in .NET that would allow for spark sql against data in the databricks cluster? Is Databricks-connect the appropriate avenue for this?

Above all, is it possible to deploy .NET application to an Azure App Service that could serve the Databricks data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way for doing that is really to use [JDBC or ODBC connected to the existing cluster or SQL Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi) - it should be supported in .Net framework via ADO.Net.  It would be easier to use than going down the route of the setting up the databricks-connect, and it will be potentially cheaper if you use SQL Analytics vs interactive clusters that are used for databricks-connect.

Comment: I was afraid it was ignorance or inexperience that was driving me to SQL/JDBC/ODBC, but it certainly does the job without complications. Thanks